# SQL Azure Data Restore possible?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I just made a boneheaded mistake.  Thinking I was connected to my local dev db, I accidentally ran the following script against my production SQL Azure database:

```
DELETE myTable
GO
```

Is my data gone for good as I fear, or does SQL Azure have some magic "Roll back to 1 hour ago" button?

Is there anything I can do to recover my table's data?

(BTW, no, I do not have a backup of the database.  SQL Azure does not support backups.  And, yes, I realize that probably answers my own question...  I just hope I'm wrong.)

Comment: Man, I've been there before - I feel for you.  And worry about me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

Azure SQL Database automatically creates backup for all Basic, Standard, and Premium databases. With these backups you can perform Point in Time Restore and recover deleted databases. These backups are also Geo-Replicated to the pair region, so in the event of a regional disaster you could recover your databases with your latest backups (1 hour RPO for V12 servers).

You can learn more about Azure SQL Database's backup and restore capabilities here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj650016.aspx.

There is also a blog on [Point in Time Restore](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/13/azure-sql-database-geo-restore/) and a blog on [Geo-Restore](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/13/azure-sql-database-geo-restore/) and a document about the [Business Continuity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh852669.aspx) offerings in Azure SQL Database.

> You probably don't want to hear this, but regular database copies seems to be your only option, i.e., http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-backup-and-restore-strategy.aspx - and must be actively done.
>
> User Error A common cause of database
>   restores is not from failure or
>   catastrophe; it is caused by user
>   error. Either a mistaken command like
>   DROP DATABASE, schema changes that
>   don’t get executed right (causing data
>   loss), or code that corrupts the data.
>   Creating backups to protect against
>   user error is the responsibility of
>   the customer and needs to be taken
>   into consideration when writing the
>   backup and restore strategy.
>
> In service update 4 of SQL Azure the
>   ability to copy the database was
>   introduced. This feature allows you to
>   copy a running database creating
>   another fully functional SQL Azure
>   database in the same data center. This
>   is a strategy you can take before
>   making any changes to the database or
>   code calling the database to create a
>   complete backup. One of the nice
>   things about this technique is that
>   the copy is a fully functional
>   database and could be restored
>   quickly. In fact, restoration might be
>   as simple as changing the applications
>   connection string to point to the copy
>   of the database.
>
> The Transact SQL looks like this:
>
> CREATE DATABASE
>   destination_database_name
>         AS COPY OF [source_server_name.]source_database_name
>   To copy the Adventure Works database
>   to the same server, I execute this:
>
> CREATE DATABASE [AdvetureWorksBackup]
>   AS COPY OF [AdventureWorksLTAZ2008R2]
>   This command must be executed when
>   connected to the master database of
>   the destination SQL Azure server.

Comment: Note that the database is "in the same data center".

Comment: Is there any way in the Azure portal to trigger a backup? i.e. create a backup on demand, before you do some Db work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of now since it's a user level error - it is not covered by the contemporary SQL Azure feature set.

I suggest you to vote for this feature on http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34685-sql-azure-feature-voting - it's a top voted 'most wanted' feature - it is officially monitored by the MS team.

HTH,